# Lived in Italy and moved to Germany, do I have to file a tax return in Italy?

Tags: germany, taxes, italy, europe

I moved to Italy last year and worked for 3 months there before moving to Germany for another job and live here since July.

I will file a tax return here for sure (mainly because I know I will get a taxback since I was overtaxed one month for lack of local knowledge).

I don't really want to bother doing so in Italy though... I earned quite a low income during those 3 months (as a salaried employee) and if I had any tax to get back it would be very low anyway.

So all of my salary in Italy was as a salaried employee, but within the same year I got a second source of income which was my job in Germany (never at the same time, left one for the other) - also as a salaried employee.

So I have to file a tax return in Italy?

BTW, I'm an Italian citizen.

Thanks!

Edit:
  This is not a duplicate of [Do Italian Citizens living abroad have to pay taxes to Italy?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/do-italian-citizens-living-abroad-have-to-pay-taxes-to-italy) as that question asks in a very generic way if any citizen living outside the country need to file the return; my question is regarding a citizen who was a resident for a short period within the year and moved to another EU country.

As per these instructions for [Italy](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/income-taxes-abroad/italy/index_en.htm) and these for [Germany](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/income-taxes-abroad/germany/index_en.htm), it is unclear, since the only source of income was as a formal employee but I have a residency move within the year.

Comment: I believe this is answered in the linked question - but if I'm missing something please do flag it to reopen.

Comment: In Portugal and Spain you need to live there more than 180 to have the obligation to file taxes there. No idea about Italy.

Comment: Yeah Italy seems to have a similar rule about paying taxes there; but I still haven't found anything clear on filing the tax return.

Comment: What did you do in the 3 months not covered by your question, i.e. from Jan  2016 to March 2016 roughly? Did you have another job in Italy? Did you declare your residences correctly and promptly? (i.e. register and de-register as a resident in Italy and Germany and wherever you were before that)

Comment: I was in Brazil, not working while I prepared for the move to Italy.

Comment: @LFLFM for which periods were you registered in Italy in that year? Did you un-register (if so when) and register for the AIRE? please tag me with `@mts` when answering in a comment so I get notified.

Comment: @mts I registered when I arrived in Rome, I was registered for about 3 months. You don't unregister in Italy, you register at the consulate of the country you moved to. If you are an Italian citizen, by law, you must do this; and you lose the Italian government health insurance benefits, so you may need to have separate insurance.Just go to the consulate and say you're living there and they will register you at the AIRE and notify the commune where you were previously registered.

Comment: You are probably right on not de-registering, only foreigners need to. My take on the tax thing is that you are probably fine not doing a declaration in Italy. From how you describe it we can leave out the period you spent in Brazil. For Italy it counts only the 3 months you were there and for Germany since when you took residence there, due to the double taxation agreement. When you only have one salaried job in Italy AFAIK you don't have to make a declaration, so good for you. Would that be enough to make it a useful answer for you? Be aware I am neither a lawyer nor a tax assistant.